# Install packages through a 2 ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh, yum, tunneling, mirror

I have the following scenario:

```
Server_A : Host that needs to get packages installed
Server_B : Host that it's used to connect to Server_A
Server_C : Host that it's used to connect to Server_B
Server_D : Host that it's a local mirror
```

Server_C can use the Server_D as mirror with the right mirror.repo file. Server_B can install packages with a ssh tunnel this way:

```
[Server_C]% ssh -R 9999:Server_D:80 Server_B
```

How can I create a new tunnel that use the first tunnel to install packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to do it by creating an new tunnel from the 2nd server. For reference the commands were:

```
[Server_C]% ssh -R 9999:Server_D:80 Server_B
[Server_B]% ssh -R 80:localhost:9999 Server_A
```